# How to prevent Tensorflow Input from generating batch dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have recently updated to the newest version of Tensorflow `2.3.1` and after updating my model doesn't work anymore:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Input(shape= input_shape), # input_shape:  (1623, 105, 105, 3)
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(ds_info.features['label'].num_classes)
    ])
```

The issue is that the Input layer adds a new `batch_size` dimension, which in turn causes the following error:

```
Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d_22 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None, 1623, 103, 103, 32]
```

How do I prevent that from being generated, or fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying input shape, you need to omit the number of samples. That's because Keras can accept any number. So try this:

```
layers.Input(shape = input_shape[1:]),
```

This will specify an input shape of `(rows, columns, channels)`, omitting the number of samples.

Comment: That solved that issue, however, the Resclaing is causing the following issue:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_34 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=0. Full shape received: []

any advice?

Comment: Uh, I think it's best if you post another question for that, it's out of scope for this one. I can't even see the rescaling operation in your code.

Comment: rescaling layer output dimensions stay the same as its input dimension, it does not change the dimensions. Try running without the rescaling layer and see if it generates the same error